# post data to search box using python request

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm trying to perform a symbol search in "https://www.investing.com", I checked the inspect tool and find out exact post request that used in search.
[post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut5ec.png)

So I use the code:

```
url = 'http://www.investing.com/search/service/search'
header = { 
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36',  
}


form_data = {
    'search_text': symbol,
    'term': symbol,
    'country_id': '0',
    'tab_id': 'All'
}
response = requests.post(url, data = form_data, headers = header)
```

Trying to land on the url: "https://www.investing.com/equities/stamps.com-inc"

However, the response always lead me to the mainpage (https://www.investing.com)
I tried to include all the headers exacting matching that in the inspect tool but still no luck.
Can someone help me with that?

Comment: oryginal request sends cookies - but cookies can change in every request so they may not work with other request. Use `Session()`, make GET request of main page and you should get new cookies only for your connections, and then make POST request still using session.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the comment. I tried what you suggested (capture the cookie from a get request and reused it in the post request) However still getting the same result. : (((